# How do I change the text in a JLabel for this app?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to program a simple button clicks counter in java, and it's supposed to be finished, but when I run it, it appear to be something wrong with the JLabel change of test in line 33, when i click the button the application crashes. How do I fix it; what I am doing wrong?
Here is the code:

```
package Main;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Eventos extends JFrame{

    JTextField clicksCounter;
    Eventos (){
        //Parámetros generales de la ventana.
        super("Eventos en Java");//Titulo de la ventana.
        setSize(320,200);//Tamaño de la ventana.
        setVisible(true);//Configurar como visible.
        setLocation(520,220);//Posicion inicial de la ventana en el medio y un poco arriba.
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//Salir al cerrrar la venta.
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        //Componentes dentro de la ventana.
        JButton ClickMe = new JButton("Haz Click aqui!");//Boton que cuenta clicks.
        add(ClickMe);//Agrega el Boton a la venatana.
        ClickMe.setSize(140, 20);
        ClickMe.setLocation(90,40);
        JTextField clicksCounter = new JTextField("Número de Clicks");//Muestra el número de clicks al boton.
        add(clicksCounter);
        ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
        ClickMe.addActionListener(handler);
    }
    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent handler){
            int times=0;
            times ++;
            clicksCounter.setText("Clicks:"+times);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why I am not able to edit the Q? 'Edit' option is disabled.

Comment: @Vikram your recent edits may have been rejected, a good amount of them.

Comment: I'd accidentally reject someone edits, may be yours @Vikram, ¿How do I enable it again?

Comment: @CodingMash and Davynch...I was trying to edit it, but I could not as 'edit' button was disabled. So, I didn't do any edits. 
Thanks for informing though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While all the other answers are partially correct, you also have one other large error. You define `clicksCounter` twice. Once in your global variables, and again within your Constructor.

See:

`JTextField clicksCounter;`

`JTextField clicksCounter = new JTextField("Número de Clicks");//Muestra el número de clicks a l boton.`

Change the second line (located within your constructor) to simply: `clicksCounter = new JTextField("Número de Clicks");//Muestra el número de clicks a l boton.`

If you don't do this, you'll get a NullPointerException.

The other problem you have is the local definition of `times` within your ActionListener. By defining `times` in your listener itself, you reset it with every click of the button, thus defeating the purpose of the counter.

Move `times` so it's outside the scope of the action listener, preferably with all other global definitions. Your action listener should then look like this:

```
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent handler){
        times++;
        clicksCounter.setText("Clicks:"+times);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right!!, there was a mistake with the times variable, but the major error was the second declaration, which makes the app crash.

Comment: Once you've implemented this change, be sure to implement the changes outlined in the other answers.

Comment: @timr update your answer to include the issue with the `times` variable issue so I can up-vote it ;)

Comment: D'oh! Good catch, I didn't even see that. +5 . . . if only I could :)

Comment: Unless `times` is used else where in the program, I might suggest to keep it within the reference of `ButtonHandler`, BUT, seen as it's updating a field within the context of the app, it might be pointless ;) +1 either way

Answer (score 2):

You create the `times` variable each time the button is clicked and the increment it...

```
int times=0;
times ++; // This will never be anything other then 1
```

Change the action listener class so that the `times` variable is maintained as part of the instance of the class

```
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
    private int times=0;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent handler){
        times ++;
        clicksCounter.setText("Clicks:"+times);
    }
}
```

You define `clicksCounter` as a instance variable, but in your constructor, you create a local instance named the same (AKA name conflict).  This means when you run the progam, the instance variable `clicksCounter` is null.

Change the constructor to remove the reference to the local variable...

```
public class Eventos extends JFrame{

    JTextField clicksCounter;
    Eventos (){
        // ... Your previous code ...
        JTextField clicksCounter = new JTextField("Número de Clicks");//Muestra el número de clicks al boton.
        // ... Your previous code ...
    }
```

Comment: got it but still, when I click the button, the app crash, and the JLabel text change doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent handler){
        int times=0;
        times ++;
        clicksCounter.setText("Clicks:"+times);
}
```

in this method, `times` is a local variable. Its value will be initialized to 0 whenever this method is called. Instead u must use:

```
private static int times=0;
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent handler) {
    times ++;
    clicksCounter.setText("Clicks:"+times);
}
```

even a better solution would be to use

```
public class Eventos extends JFrame implements ActionListener
```

and use `times` as non static variable `private int times=0;`

Answer (score 0):

`times` needs to be a member variable, either of your `Eventos` class, or of `ButtonHandler`. As it is, it will be instantiated as `0` every time your button is clicked, since it's a local variable.